# Do not trap home key for TV PC

Tags: keyboard, windows, external-keyboard

I recently changed out several android TV PCs to TX92 hardware with android 7.1.2. I use them to remote into Windows as a thin client among other things. The last nuisance remaining is the home key. If using Windows and I press the home key on the keyboard, android goes back to the launcher screen. How can I disable this? The units are rooted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this is possible.

From [Android Developer Center](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME) (Google's official site):

> Key code constant: Home key.
>
> This key is **handled by the framework** and is never delivered to applications.

And the Home key on a generic QWERTY keyboard is mapped to the Android "home" button, so it's treated the same as the real home button.

You can try modifying `/system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl` but as per my attempts, it doesn't work. Just in case it would work for you, for what it's worth, I changed

```
key 102   HOME
```

to

```
key 172   HOME
```

Comment: The boxes I replaced had android 4.4.2, I think it was, and there was an option in settings whether the OS should recognize keyboard hotkeys. In many ways they worked better than what I have now with 7.1.2. The processor was just too slow. I waited a long time to swap out.

Comment: This worked! There was a note inside qwerty.kl saying it isn't the default for android any longer, but Generic.kl. I commented out anything saying home, which did not work, but did the same for all files in the folder. Some had a home assignment, some did not. Probably a vendor specific file is being used.
For people reading, you must reboot after changing keyboard files for change to take effect.